# WSL not enabled in "Turn Windows features on or off"

Tags: windows, virtualization, windows-11, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I am on Windows 11 (22H2) Professional Edition. I enabled WSL2 by doing `wsl --install`. I did a test run by downloading Ubuntu 20.02 from Microsoft Store and it works perfectly.

However, the option "Windows Subsystem for Linux" is not enabled in the "Turn Windows features on or off" menu.
Why can I use WSL without enabling the corresponding feature? What additional functionalities will I get by enabling it?

[image]

Comment: What happens when you try to enable it? Before I spend time researching I need that bit of information.

Comment: @Ramhound I am hesitant to enable it since WSL now appears to be in an inconsistent status and I fear changing something will break it, but I am happy to do so if you need that information. Is there any diagnostic command you want me to execute before/after enabling it?

Comment: @Ramhound Ah wait a second, the menu item probably refers to WSL1. See my answer below.

Comment: It actually does not. It installs the legacy WSL which of course supports both WSL1 and WSL2. While the command you run installs the Windows Store version of WSL which only supports WSL2, and is the only version update, and only supported on supported builds of Windows 10 and Windows 11.

Comment: @Ramhound: I think you should put up a corrective answer.

Comment: @harrymc - I think the author should just fix their answer

Answer (score 0):

Note that

```
> wsl --status
Default Distribution: Ubuntu
Default Version: 2
WSL1 is not supported with your current machine configuration.
Please enable the "Windows Subsystem for Linux" optional component to use WSL1.
```

As @Ramhound pointed out, the menu item in "Turn Windows features on or off" installs the legacy WSL which of course supports both WSL1 and WSL2, while `wsl --install` installs the Windows Store version of WSL which only supports WSL2, and is the only version update, and only supported on supported builds of Windows 10 and Windows 11 (i.e. Professional and Enterprise).